# Forcing callback to async

Tags: javascript

So i am using [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md) guide to learn about async-ish behavior in JS. The example i am unable to wrap my head around is this

```
function asyncify(fn) {
    var orig_fn = fn,
        intv = setTimeout( function(){
            intv = null;
            if (fn) fn();
        }, 0 )
    ;

    fn = null;

    return function() {
        // firing too quickly, before `intv` timer has fired to
        // indicate async turn has passed?
        if (intv) {
            fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(
                orig_fn,
                // add the wrapper's `this` to the `bind(..)`
                // call parameters, as well as currying any
                // passed in parameters
                [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
        }
        // already async
        else {
            // invoke original function
            orig_fn.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    };
}
```

Usage :

```
function result(data) {
    console.log( a );
}

var a = 0;

ajax( "..pre-cached-url..", asyncify( result ) );
a++;
```

So conceptually I understand it is attempting to force a function which would execute immediately , to run on the next tick of the event loop, which allows the variable a to be set to the value 1 and hence will always print 1.

The setTimeout section , is the part where I presume , it pushes the call to the next tick of the event loop. However, I am completely lost on the return section of the code.

Q) I know intv will be the timer id, what on earth is the black magic of orgin_fn.bind.apply mean. I know bind , ahem binds a value to a function to be called later , apply passes a this object and and argument array, but I am having a hard time understanding the entire invocation flow and I have never seen fb.bind.apply.

Q)The this object resolves to the Window when i run the code in the browser, why are all the arguments being concatenated on the window (global in this case) object.

Q)I understand this is POC, but is there a legitimate reason to have an else block here which executes the function any way. In which scenario do i see this being executed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orig_fn.bind.apply` thing is in the replacement for the synchronous callback. It's creating a new function that, when called, will call the original function with the same `this` and arguments it (the replacement) was called with, and assigning that function to `fn`. This is so that later when the timer goes off and it calls `fn`, it calls the original function with the correct `this` and arguments. (See [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply); the tricky bit is that it's using `apply` on `bind` itself, passing in `orig_fn` as `this` for the `bind` call.)

The `if`/`else` is so that if the replacement is called before the timer goes off (`intv` is truthy), it doesn't call `orig_fn` right away, it waits by doing the above and assigning the result to `fn`. But if the timer has gone off (`intv` is `null` and thus falsy), it calls the original function right away, synchronously.

Normally, you wouldn't want to create a function that's chaotic like that (sometimes doing something asynchronously, sometimes doing it synchronously), but in this particular case, the reason is that it's ensuring that the function it wraps is *always* called asynchronously: If the function is called during the same job/task* as when `asyncify` was called, it waits to call the original function until the timer has fired; but if it's already on a different job/task, it does it right away.

A more modern version of that function might use a promise, since in current environments, a promise settlement callback happens *as soon as possible* after the current job; on browsers, that means it happens before a timer callback would. (Promise settlement callbacks are so-called "microtasks" vs. timer and event "macrotasks." Any microtasks scheduled during a macrotask are executed when that macrotask completes, before any previously-scheduled next macrotask.)

---

* job = [JavaScript terminology](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues), task = [browser terminology](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-loops)

Comment: I've been under the impression that 'this' object is the context from which the object was called. Is it correct to say that 'this' argument can also be a function (for apply/call)?
So I assume in fn.bind.apply , the apply is called first , followed by bind ? or is it just setting the apply property on the bind property. Sorry If i sound confused.

Comment: @RickMota: `this` isn't a context at all, nor is it a scope, though people commonly use those terms in relation to it. `this` is...`this`. :-) It's effectively a somewhat-hidden argument, which is determined by how the function is called (usually). [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/). Yes, `this` can be a reference to a function, and you're spot-on that when calling `Function#bind`, we want `this` to refer to the function we want to bind (which is why the more normal version `newFunction = someFunction.bind(...)` works; `bind` use `this`, which his set to `someFunction`).

Comment: (Re the *"...determined by how the function is called (usually)..."* above: Arrow functions, and functions that already have a `this` bound to them, ignore any `this` they're called with. Instead, an arrow function *closes over* the `this` in its parent context just like it would a variable declared in that context, and of course, a bound function uses the `this` bound to it.)

Comment: (Re "context": I don't like using "context" for `this`, though it frequently is used that way -- less so now than a few years ago -- because "context" already has a meaning in JavaScript in the form of [execution contexts](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts), which are not what `this` is [but to make matters worse, sometimes indirectly contain the value for `this` for the execution context] via the current [lexical environment](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-lexical-environments) for the context.)

Comment: Finally (talk about rambling!), FWIW, the best thing to call `this` in my view is a "`this` binding". That's what the spec calls it. ("Bindings" are how JavaScript resolves variables, parameters, declared function names, `this`, `super`, and a few other things. A binding is like an object property, with a name and value, but the object holding them -- the lexical environment record -- is conceptual rather than literal. Probably. It's up to the implementation.)